# Set a static ip to a container using the default docker subnet

Tags: docker, docker-container, docker-network

I need to use gdbserver in a docker container.
As the use of gdb in the host is scripted I need to set a static IP for my container.

The output of ifconfig is :

```
docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        inet6 ****::**:****:****:****  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether **:**:**:**:**:**  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 60  bytes 8931 (8.9 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I have tried :

```
docker run --name "myContainerName" --ip 172.17.0.124 --rm -it -p 7777:7777 myImgae /bin/bash
```

But inside the docker I get the output of ifconfig :

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr ***:**:**:**:**:**
          inet addr:172.17.0.2  Bcast:172.17.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:16 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:2282 (2.2 KiB)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

The IP of my container is `172.17.0.2` and not `172.17.0.124` as I want

So I am wondering how the ip option works with the default subnet (docker0)

Comment: Can you use the `docker run -p` option to publish the debugger port, and then connect to it using `localhost` from the host system?  In many many environments the container-private IP addresses aren't usable, but published ports are fairly reliable.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by an answer,
I found a workaround using "localhost" for my debuggind session instead of a specific ip address

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).